# Cannot modify header information Проблема с заголовками

Tags: php, include

Ох уж эти заголовки...

> Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at C:\OpenServer\domains\web.ru\include\header.php:14) in C:\OpenServer\domains\web.ru\index.php on line 4

Файл index.php

```
<?php
    include_once 'include/header.php';
    if(empty($_SESSION["id"])) {
        header("location:login.php");
    }
?>
test
</body>
</html>
```

Файл include/header.php

```
<?php
    session_start();
    include '/rb.php';
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>title</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/style.css" type="text/css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/font-awesome.css" type="text/css">
    </head>
    <body>
```

Два раза заголовки не передаю.
Файлы сохраняю без BOM, даже если header.php оставлять пустой, то всё равно ругается. Если в индексе заменить условие на !empty, то такой проблемы нет

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ох уж эти пользователи РНР. Никак не усвоят, что [НТТР заголовки выводятся ДО HTML](http://phpfaq.ru/newbie/headers).

Команда `header("location:login.php");` у нас делает что? **Выводит НТТР заголовок.**

Команда `include_once 'include/header.php';` у нас делает что? **Выводит HTML**

Чтобы решить данную невероятно сложную проблему надо что? **Поменять эти две команды местами.** Чтобы НТТР заголовоr выводился до HTML.

Для этого надо сделать так, чтобы header.php занимался чем-то одним. А именно выводил HTML. А старт сессии и неведомое rb.php надо перенести куда-то еще.